# Would an js `Number` type add up to Infinity?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

If given enough time, will this loop finish?

```
for (let i = 0; 1 / i > 0; i++) {} // js code [0]
```

I guess it would when `i` reaches `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` but don't know how to test this.

**edit**:

```
for (let i = 0; 1 / i > 0; i += k) {} // js code [1]
```

1. What's the smallest positive number `k` that makes **js code [1]** finish? (At least `k = 1e304` would)
2. Let's assume answer to question 1 to be `K`, does any number greater than `K` guarantees finish of **js code [1]**?

Comment: But `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is greater than zero, and adding 1 to `Infinity` gives `Infinity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest positive `k` for which `for (let i = 0; 1 / i > 0; i += k) {}` completes is 2<sup>970</sup>+2<sup>918</sup>, which is 9979201547673601274109728685629478266941425536662556495940151194794704206738934042339246016744483498432906272845056291604255807740315814654641757203776116733684667887776747567741590850984835485160546300028847034430406236117424720216135936743286628244379070620554941694189420489857797422317568.

JavaScript is a dialect of [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), which specifies that it uses the 64-bit (binary) IEEE-754 floating-point format with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even. In this format, the largest finite numbers are in the binade from 2<sup>1023</sup> (inclusive) to 2<sup>1024</sup> (exclusive). Since the significand (fraction portion) of the floating-point number has 53 bits, the least significant bit of these numbers has position value 2<sup>1023−52</sup> = 2<sup>971</sup>. This is called the unit of least precision (ULP). (The ULP is a function of the exponent of a floating-point number; it scales with the number.)

When `i+k` is computed, the result is rounded to the nearest representable number. If `k` is less than ½ ULP of `i`, then the representable number nearest to the mathematical value of `i` + `k` is `i`, so no change occurs when `i = i+k` is performed. If `k` is exactly ½ ULP of `i`, then the mathematical value of `i` + `k` is exactly halfway between `i` and the next representable value. According to the round-to-nearest-ties-to-even rule, this will be rounded down if the low bit of `i` is zero and up if it is one. Thus, if `k` is exactly ½ ULP of the largest finite floating-point numbers, `i = i+k` will produce no change for half of them, so the loop will not progress.

If `k` exceeds ½ ULP of `i`, then the mathematical value of `i` + `k` is closer to the next greater representable value than it is to `i`, so the result is `i` plus one ULP, so the loop progresses. (In the special case where `i` is the largest representable finite value, the addition will produce infinity, which then ends the loop since `1 / i` will be zero.)

As stated above, the ULP of the largest values is 2<sup>971</sup>. ½ ULP is 2<sup>970</sup>. We need `k` to be larger than this by the smallest amount possible, so we want to add one ULP to it. (One ULP at its scale, not the ULP of the largest numbers.) The ULP of 2<sup>970</sup> is 2<sup>970−52</sup> = 2<sup>918</sup>.

Therefore, the smallest positive `k` that causes the loop to terminate is 2<sup>970</sup>+2<sup>918</sup>.

Answer (score 6):

No, it will never finish, because at high numbers, number precision fails. For example, adding `1` to `1e16` results in a number which is also equal to `1e16` - past a certain point, it'll never progress:

```js
console.log((1e16 + 1) === 1e16);
```

That point is `9007199254740992`. Javascript's `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9007199254740991`. Adding one to `9007199254740991` results in `9007199254740992`, but adding one to `9007199254740992` results in the same number, `9007199254740992`:

```js
console.log(9007199254740991 + 1 === 9007199254740992);
console.log(9007199254740992 + 1 === 9007199254740992);
```

You get to `Infinity` around `1.7e308`.

Comment: Or `Infinity + 1` is `Infinity`, which makes sense.

Comment: the exact "certain point" is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740991)